# "null object reference" error in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I used my app's resize handler to resize my component but it is throwing this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
```

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           resize="application2_resizeHandler(event)" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            private var employeeName:String = 'ravi';

            protected function application2_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {
                mainGroup.width = stage.width - 10;
                mainGroup.x = 5;                    
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup id="mainGroup" >
            <s:Label id="employeeNameLabel" text="{employeeName}" />
            <s:Label id="departmentLabel"  />
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:Button id="getData" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: You should be more specific and explain what part of null object reference you don't understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got the #1009 error because your `resize` event is fired before the creation of your objects. So, you should wait for that and that your app is added to the stage to be able to use the stage object.

For that, I think that the best event is the [`applicationComplete`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html#event:applicationComplete) event, then you can add a `resize` event to resize your component ...

So you can do like this for example :

```
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
    applicationComplete="application2_applicationCompleteHandler(event)" >
```

then

```
protected function application2_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // if you want you can resize your component for the 1st time
    // by calling the application2_resizeHandler() function
    application2_resizeHandler(new ResizeEvent(ResizeEvent.RESIZE));

    // add the resize event listener to your app
    event.target.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, application2_resizeHandler);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I would appreciate if the person who downvoted my post tell me what's wrong with it.